# Java split with the characters that are not the indicated delimiters for .csv file

Tags: java, string, split

I have this string:

```
String newstring = "2018 Panini PRIZM DEVONTE GRAHAM SILVER Prizm #288 ROOKIE PSA 10 GEM MT HORNETS /split/ 2017-18 Panini Prizm Prizms Silver #16 Jayson Tatum Rookie PSA 10 Gem Mint RC"
```

I am currently using the split function as `newstring.split("/split/")` to obtain the two separate strings, then output as on a .csv file, and it works fine.

However, now I am given this string:

```
String anotherstring = " 2017-18 Panini Prizm Prizms Silver #16 Jayson Tatum Rookie PSA 10 Gem Mint RC /split/ Ja Morant prizm rc , silver, base, college, PSA 10? Great cards no scratches"
```

If I use the code above on `anotherstring`, I will have 6 strings, but not 2 as I expect. From what I tested, the split function also split by the comma sign which was not what I indicated as the delimiter. I think that my problem is that I am trying to export it as a .csv file. But how can I still export the file as .csv but not getting the values sprinkled?

**EDIT:**

Here are the Strings that I obtained in the .csv file when I run the code:

```
2017-18 Panini Prizm Prizms Silver #16 Jayson Tatum Rookie PSA 10 Gem Mint RC
Ja Morant prizm rc 
silver
base
college
?? PSA 10? Great cards no scratches
```

Comment: `String arr [] = anotherstring.split("/split/"); 
  
  System.out.println(arr.length);`  prints the value `2`

Comment: Sorry I think that I misled the question a little bit. I was actually exporting the file to a .csv file.

Comment: well the c of csv means comma.  Did you try using a proper csv file writer like opencsv?  The string values would need to be quoted if the contain a comma.

Comment: Ah I did not think of the quote actually. I'm using JSoup to parse a HTML, so I will need to think of a way to put the parsed info into a quote. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: No point re-inventing the wheel - use opencsv.

Comment: Got it! I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can include commas inside csv's you just need to ensure that the entire piece of data is quoted. Here is an example:

1,2,a,b,3 will be 5 string however 1,2,"a,b",3 is only 4 strings.